# Robot Framework : How to add documentation tag for test written in BDD + DD style

Tags: tags, robotframework, documentation, bdd

Following is my test is written in Robot Framework. It uses the BDD+data-driven approach. It runs perfectly fine. Bue how to add [Documentation] tag for each test. I want that in the report.html, for each test case, documentation should be displayed. How to achieve it?

```
Settings

Resource …/…/…/resources/high-level-api.robot

Library Collections

Test Template this is my test

Test Cases

TC1 ${data1} ${data2}

TC2 ${data3} ${data4}

TC3 ${data5} ${data6}

Keywords

this is my test

[Arguments]     ${valid_data1}        ${valid_data2}

When perform step1        ${valid_data1}

And step2                           ${valid_data1}

Then I should get              ${valid_data2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Documentation] setting from user [guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-case-name-and-documentation).
It should look something like this:

```
***Settings***
Test Template    Log Value    
*** Test Cases ***    VALUE
Example               dummy 
    [Documentation]    first example


Example 2             Value
    [Documentation]    second example

*** Keywords ***
Log Value
    [Arguments]     ${value}
    Log    ${value}
```